# describeVpnGateways function returns empty list while using AWS SDK Java library

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am using AWS SDK 1.11.30 Java library. I am trying to retrieve virtual private gateways  using AmaznonEC2 interfaces as follows:

```
public List<VpnGateway> describeVpnGateways(AwsAccount account, Region region) {
            // I am providing correct access and secret keys and region
            AmazonEC2 ec2 = findClient(account, region);

            DescribeVpnGatewaysRequest req = new DescribeVpnGatewaysRequest();

            DescribeVpnGatewaysResult res = ec2.describeVpnGateways(req);
            if (res != null) {
                    List<VpnGateway> vpnGateways = res.getVpnGateways();

                    logger.info("Describe VPN gateway:"+vpnGateways.size());
                    return vpnGateways;
            }

            return null;
    }
```

But I am getting the empty list. If I try to fetch using AWS CLI, I get correct result. The same thing is happening for VPN connections as well.

However I am able to fetch VPCs, subnets, Route Tables, and intenet gateways using AWS SDK java library.

Link to AmazonEC2 class:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2.html

Any help will highly be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the CLI and your Java code are set to use the same AWS region?

Comment: Yes I am using the same AWS region. I am able to get VPCs using SDK library from same region.